# Multiplying a 2D and 1D array to obtain a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array `A` of probabilities, and a 1D array `B` of a normal distribution.  I would like to multiply each probability in `A` by `B`, such that the resulting array `C` is now 3-dimensional, with the third axis now the length of the original 1D array `B`.

What would be the most pythonic way of performing this operation?

Comment: `A[...,None]*B`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> A = np.array([[0.2, 0.3],
                [0.1, 0.4]])

>>> B = np.array([1,2,3])

>>> C = A[...,None] * B
array([[[0.2, 0.4, 0.6],
        [0.3, 0.6, 0.9]],

       [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
        [0.4, 0.8, 1.2]]])

>>> C.shape
(2, 2, 3)
```